# .NET 4.5.1 versus .NET Core 5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We want to use the "vNext" technology in our next project.

[image: DLL Compatibility]

For me it looks like we can only use the framework version 4.5.1 when we rely on libraries like Serilog or mongoDB that have dependencies on older Framework Versions.
Is this really true or is there a way to have dependencies that rely on the full old framework version and the project itself depends on .NET Core 5.0?

Comment: Your second question is extremely vague. It's a bad idea to ask two questions in one post anyway - I suggest you remove it, and if you still want to ask it, think of a more specific way of asking it in a different post. It would help if you'd give references for the various claims, too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Only answering the first of your questions as the second seems too broad and/or vague...)

> Is this really true or is there a way to have dependencies that rely on the full old framework version and the project itself depends on .NET Core 5.0?

Yes, it's really true - and makes perfect sense, IMO. You're saying "I want my app to be able to run on .NET Core." How is that going to work if some of the libraries you're depending on try to use features that don't exist in .NET Core?

I suspect this will get a *lot* better soon though - as soon as things have stabilized a bit and it's easier for open source projects to build .NET Core-enabled NuGet packages, I'd expect most projects that aim for portability to do their best to support it.

(Part of this will depend on tooling though - I gather that *right now* the only way of building a package which works with .NET Core is to use a vNext-style project, rather than a "regular" VS class library project with a specific PCL profile. I hope this will change, but we'll see.)

Comment: In the C++ native world you may use a shared library DLL that is completely independent of your own application. I was just thinking that this should be possible here too.

Comment: @Matthias: But you'd have a hard time using a DLL built using Windows 8 features but running it on Windows 95, wouldn't you? That's the sort of thing you're asking for here. The environment in which you're deploying the code determines what code you can deploy. I don't see anything surprising about that.

Comment: It is just that I was thinking one could have an II server installed where multiple .NET frameworks are available. So the main application could use one framework where a "dependency" (in what form ever possible) could rely on another.

Comment: @Matthias: No, you don't end up running an application under multiple frameworks at the same time. And even if you *could*, it would mean that your application which you were trying to build to only require .NET Core would *actually* require the full framework... in which case why not depend on the full framework to start with?

Comment: Just in order to ensure that we do not end up having dependencies on the old API only because some of the dependencies do so. Just to be prepared for the .NET core.

Comment: @Matthias: Well that doesn't really fly - an application targeting .NET Core is meant to be able to *run* on .NET Core. I can see what you're trying to do, but that's not what the framework targeting is for.

Comment: Mostly-irrelevant note on Serilog - .NET core _is_ supported at present, but only `.WriteTo.TextWriter()` is available on that platform (using e.g. `.WriteTo.Console()` still needs the full .NET. That will definitely change soon :-)